# No Voice Communication when call is streaming using CallKit

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession, linphone, callkit

I was trying to make a call from extension 100(Linphone App) to 102(My application). The extension 102 has shown the incoming call screen and then clicked accept button and then, extension 100 starts to talk to extension 102 but extension 102 unable to hear anything from 100 and also extension 100 unable to hear from 102 as well.

I think the problem because of app. But i don't know what is wrong with my application.

These functions i declared in `appdelegate` file in order to handle incoming call

```
let callKitManager = CallKitCallInit(uuid: UUID(), handle: "")

lazy var providerDelegate: ProviderDelegate = ProviderDelegate(callKitManager: self.callKitManager)


func displayIncomingCall(uuid: UUID, handle: String, completion: ((NSError?) -> Void)?) {
    providerDelegate.reportIncomingCall(uuid: uuid, handle: handle, completion: completion)
}
```

This is `ProviderDelegate` file

```
extension ProviderDelegate: CXProviderDelegate {

func providerDidReset(_ provider: CXProvider) {
    print("Stop Audio ==STOP-AUDIO==")

    for call in callKitManager.calls {
        call.end(uuid: UUID())
    }

    callKitManager.removeAllCalls()
}

func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction) {

    guard let call = callKitManager.callWithUUID(uuid: action.callUUID) else {
        action.fail()
        return
    }

    configureAudioSession()

    call.answer()

    action.fulfill()

}

func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXEndCallAction) {

    guard let call = callKitManager.callWithUUID(uuid: action.callUUID) else {
        action.fail()
        return
    }


    print("Stop audio ==STOP-AUDIO==")
    configureAudioSession()

    call.end(uuid: action.callUUID)


    action.fulfill()

    callKitManager.remove(call: call)
}


func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, didActivate audioSession: AVAudioSession) {
    print("Starting audio ==STARTING-AUDIO==")
}


func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, didDeactivate audioSession: AVAudioSession) {
    print("Received \(#function)")
}

func configureAudioSession() {
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try? session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        try? session.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat)
        try? session.setPreferredSampleRate(44100.0)
        try? session.setPreferredIOBufferDuration(0.005)
        try? session.setActive(true)
    } 

    }
 }

class ProviderDelegate: NSObject {

fileprivate let callKitManager: CallKitCallInit
fileprivate let provider: CXProvider

init(callKitManager: CallKitCallInit) {
    self.callKitManager = callKitManager

    provider = CXProvider(configuration: type(of: self).providerConfiguration)

    super.init()

    provider.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)

}


static var providerConfiguration: CXProviderConfiguration {
    let providerConfiguration = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: "vKclub")

    providerConfiguration.supportsVideo = false
    providerConfiguration.maximumCallsPerCallGroup = 1
    providerConfiguration.supportedHandleTypes = [.phoneNumber]
    return providerConfiguration
}

func reportIncomingCall(uuid: UUID, handle: String, hasVideo: Bool = false, completion: ((NSError?) -> Void)?) {

    print("This is UUID === ", uuid)
    configureAudioSession()
    let update = CXCallUpdate()
    update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .phoneNumber, value: handle)
    update.hasVideo = hasVideo


    provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: uuid, update: update) { error in


        if error == nil {
            // 3.
            self.configureAudioSession()
            let call = CallKitCallInit(uuid: uuid, handle: handle)
            self.callKitManager.add(call: call)
            lastCallUUID = uuid
            print("UUID === ", uuid)
        } else {

        }

        // 4.
        completion?(error as NSError?)
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Hello visal,
have you got any solution because I have the same problem using pjsip?
please help me if found any solution then.

Comment: @ShraddhaVaishnani I have figured my issue by adding `action.fulfill()` inside `func provider(_ provider: CXProvider,`

Comment: You should only call this method from the implementation of a CXProviderDelegate method.

Comment: @vishal
thank you it's working